# I want to scrap a website and get all links with title in selenium, but i got stale element issue once i navigated from home page and swtich back

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, staleelementreferenceexception

I am doing a selenium project, to scrap all links in a web page and click on it, then get title and description of the news.
I want to do this for all links in the home page - say bbc.com
but once I click on a link and switch back, the home page got refreshed.
and remaining links showing as stale element issue. Her is my code
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
       

    for(int el = 0; el < allLinks.size(); el++) {
        
        hrefs = allLinks.get(el).getAttribute("href");
                
            try {
                allLinks.get(el).click();
                //newpage = driver.getWindowHandle();
                try {
                    text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("*//div[contains(@class,'title-text')]")).getText();
                    description = driver.findElement(By.xpath("*//div[contains(@class,'title-text')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'title')]/following::h2[contains(@class,'subtitle')]")).getText();
                     noSwitch = false; 
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println("Page not navigated");
                }           
                 
            } catch(StaleElementReferenceException e) {
                System.out.println("Stale element issue");
                text = allLinks.get(el).getText();
                description = "No Description.";
            }
              
        
            
            System.out.println(hrefs + " - "+ text + " - " + description);
            
            utility.setCellData("first sheet", rowcnt, 1, text);
            utility.setCellData("first sheet", rowcnt, 2, hrefs);
            utility.setCellData("first sheet", rowcnt, 3, description);
            rowcnt++;
            if(!noSwitch) {
               driver.switchTo().window(homepage);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Get a list of href values and then navigate to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to recall your links, so reload allLinks like that:

```
List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for(int el = 0; el < allLinks.size(); el++) {
    #add this line       
    allLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I have resolved by getting all the hrefs into a string array and pass over each by driver.get(href);